# определить палиндром строки нечетной длины

Tags: регулярные-выражения

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Имеется строка
необходимо что бы регулярка записывала в группы вариант 55555 подобно 7777777
то есть что бы слева и справа от середины было одинаковое количество символов

55|5|55

`\b((\w{1,3})(\B\w\B)(\w{1,3}))\b`
`aaa qwq 1234567 7777777 55555`

Comment: Как бы не совсем для регулярных выражений задача. См. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233243/how-to-check-that-a-string-is-a-palindrome-using-regular-expressions

Answer (score 1):

Вариант регулярки

```
(\w+)(\w)(\1)
```

[Демо](https://regex101.com/r/gGInKX/1)

Не понял насчет 1234567 - почему подкрашивается - это явно не палиндром.

Для четной и нечетной длин строки:

```
(\w+)(\w)?(\1)
```